# Anyone at JSM 2011?

Tags: discussion

Should've asked this about three days ago.  But anyone still around [JSM](http://www.amstat.org/meetings/jsm/2011/)?

Comment: Perhaps next year then.  (I'll try and remember earlier)

Comment: If the idea is to de-virtualize, it's not too difficult to set up a meeting, even a semi-official one, that could go on a program. I've been doing this for a number of years to gather together statisticians from home country :).

Answer (score 2):

Nope. However, if you're willing to share your thoughts about the conference, go join us at [Skewed Distribution](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/549/skewed-distribution): It would be great to have a short summary of the most exciting talks on the [community blog](http://stats.blogoverflow.com/).

Comment: I'm not important enough of a statistician to do so. (I'm still a grad student for one more week. ;O) )

Comment: @MTibbits Even better -- fresh perspective.